# TinyMCE link button & popup: get rid of items in class dropdown list

Tags: css, hyperlink, tinymce

In TinyMCE, when a user clicks the link button, a popup window appears prompting for link information. One of the fields in this popup is for css "Class".

How can you clear this list? I saw there is a plugin setting for the advlink which allows you to provide a list of css classes, but I don't want to use advlink as I don't want the popup and other tabs in the link window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the `content_css : "/css/mycss.css"` line in your TinyMCE configuration, the Class dropdown won't appear in the link popup since it won't be aware of what styles are present in your site's CSS anymore.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Ultimately I ended up changing the content_css to a different stylesheet file, so that I can control the dropdown items manually. Minus one -1 for tinymce though.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this tinymce exmaple](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/custom_formats.php). A look at the configuration will show you the following setting ([style_formats](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3astyle_formats))

```
    // Style formats
    style_formats : [
            {title : 'Bold text', inline : 'b'},
            {title : 'Red text', inline : 'span', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
            {title : 'Red header', block : 'h1', styles : {color : '#ff0000'}},
            {title : 'Example 1', inline : 'span', classes : 'example1'},
            {title : 'Example 2', inline : 'span', classes : 'example2'},
            {title : 'Table styles'},
            {title : 'Table row 1', selector : 'tr', classes : 'tablerow1'}
    ],
```

using this tinymce configuration setting you are able to define what styles appear in the style dropdown list AND the css field of the link popup.

**Update:** Unfortunately the above does not influence the class dropdown int he popup.
Here is the correct way configuration example setting

```
 advlink_styles: 'Code=code;Excel=excel;Flash=flash;Sound=sound;'
```

You are using the advlink plugin already, so there is nothing wrong in using this configuration setting. Give it a try.

Comment: I've tried this, and specifying style_formats only affects the styleselect dropdown, not the "class" dropdown in the link popup.

Comment: I think there is some confusion... we do not use the advlink plugin, and do not want to (see the OP).

Comment: The normal "link" button, without the advlink plugin. It looks like this in the code: `plugins: 'save,autosave,paste,searchreplace,table,nonbreaking',` then `theme_advanced_buttons1: 'save,undo,redo,restoredraft,|,formatselect,bold,italic,underline,|,link,unlink`, ... notice the use of the "link" button while ommitting the "advlink" plugin.

Comment: as i thought: there are only the fields 'Lmik Url', 'Target' and 'Title' - not "CSS" (that one is available using the advlink plugin only)